# Can we have two primary key in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm a new Elasticsearch. How can we set two primary keys using the object IndexRequest? I sent data using RestHighLevelClient. Thank you for helping me here.

Comment: Elasticsearch doesn't have primary (or secondary) keys, so what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Elasticsearch documents have an id, this is unique insofar as when you store a second document under an existing id, it overwrites the first. This is can be used for direct access, so it's a kind of primary id. But having more than one primary key - in any system - would mean that it's not primary anymore.

Comment: For completeness' sake, just a quick side note here to mention that it is indeed possible to have two documents with the same `_id` value in the same index, provided that index has more than one primary shard and if both documents are indexed with a different [routing value](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/mapping-routing-field.html). No idea why anyone would ever need something like this (asking for troubles), but it's possible.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. now I can understand it from your explanation.